# real valued differentiable function with a condition

Tags: real-analysis

> Will be glad for a little hint for this one; f is a real valued differentiable function defined on $[1,\infty)$ with $f(1)=1.$ Suppose moreover f satisfies $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}$$ Show that $f(x)\le 1+\frac{\pi}{4}$

[source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

Comment: Note that, $f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{x^2+1},$ since $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the given condition  $f'(x)={1\over x^2+f^2(x)}$, it follows that   $f'$ is positive on $[1,\infty)$. So $f$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$, and since $f(1)=1$, we have $f(x)\ge1$ on $[1,\infty)$.
The aforementioned condition also implies that $f'$ is continuous on $[1,\infty)$. We thus have 
$$
f(t)-f(1)=\int_1^t {1\over x^2+f^2(x)}\,dx\le \int_1^\infty{1\over 1+x^2}\,dx=\tan^{-1} x\,\bigl|_1^\infty={\pi\over 4};
$$
whence the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this initial value problem has a closed-form implicit solution:
$$ \frac{x Y_{1/4}(f(x)^2/2) - f(x) Y_{-3/4}(f(x)^2/2)}{x J_{1/4}(f(x)^2/2) + f(x) J_{-3/4}(f(x)^2/2)}
= \frac{Y_{1/4}(1/2) + Y_{-3/4}(1/2)}{J_{1/4}(1/2) + J_{-3/4}(1/2)}$$
where $J$ and $Y$ are Bessel functions of the first and second kinds.
The actual limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ is approximately $1.729444022$.